# Bypass or turn off [Authorize(Roles="")] during development?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, authorize-attribute

Building an MVC3 application, and TPTB want us to use their custom authorization provider. However, during development this auth provider is kind of a pain, since it will either give an error til you shut down/restart the browser, or it will require you to re-log o on every compile.

For now, I just added `<authentication mode="None"/>` to the web.config, which works fine until I encounter an action or controller that uses the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` filter (it can be any role, not just Admin). When it hits one of those, it just renders a blank page.

Is there a way globally and temporarily turn these filters off? Or just give the user all roles while I'm in development?

**EDIT**

Let me clarify- I'm actually porting over a large app from MVC2 to MVC3. It has lots of `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` and `[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Editor")]` throughout it. I'd rather not change all of those if possible.

Should I just create a small custom role provider that gives all roles automatically?

Comment: Anri's answer is better, because it does not allow to use http proxy exploit to get admin right on the server.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could write a custom Authorize filter which will not perform any checks if the request is coming from `localhost`:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Url.IsLoopback)
        {
            // It was a local request => authorize the guy
            return true;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. I realized quickly that a search/replace of the Authorize attribute was a lot easier than anything else I was considering!

Comment: what about rather checking Request.IsLocal ? I think it's more "bulletproof".

Comment: You should add a #if DEBUG around the return entire if block -- otherwise you're opening up a potential data loss issue in production. What's to stop a nefarious admin going to IE in production and typing http://127.0.0.1/refundCC?CC=1234689&amount=infinity

Comment: I often like to do `if (Debugger.IsAttached)` .. for cases like this

Answer (score 17):

You can inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` and separate realizations with `#if DEBUG` directive.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
#if DEBUG
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
#endif
}
```

Or `#define YOUR_OWN_FLAG` to turn behavior on and off in any build, debug or release.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to MVC, where do you put the above code? Every single controller? Startup Class?

Comment: Each controller, yes, although not that this is an answer from 6 years ago, I don't use .NET for 4 years now and have no idea what is the right way to do it today.

Comment: "although not" = "although note"

Answer (score 8):

For Web API:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return actionContext.Request.RequestUri.IsLoopback || base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing for the Loopback is awesome haha why didnt I think of that

Comment: For those of us who don't write our own attributes very often... the above code is defining a custom attribute which you only have to do once (like in your base controller). To use the custom authorize attribute put this code on your controller (or base controller): `[MyAuthorize(Roles="Admin")]`

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this and end up resolving like below code. You could just add AllowAnonymousFilter in development environment which will disable authorization in development environment.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
services.AddMvc(opts =>
{
   opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
});
} else {
 services.AddMvc();
}
```