# Set admin role during development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, authorize-attribute

Building an MVC5 application and I am using my custom authorization with windows authentication. The live project is authenticating from an active directory. During development I want the anonymous user to access the app as administrator as that would help me during the development process.

My custom class:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        #if DEBUG
            //TODO: set anonymous user as administrator during developement
            return true;
        #else
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        #endif
    }
}
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767527/bypass-or-turn-off-authorizeroles-during-development) helped me a lot but I just need to add the admin role if possible.

Is there a way to add a role to the anonymous user during the development process?  For me to use the attribute as such in debug mode

```
User.IsInRole("Admin") == true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a user in the startup.cs.

```
if (_user == null){
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "Administrator",
                    Email = "youremail",
                    RoleId = 1
                };

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,"yourpassword");
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
```